# Read-only access to external mailbox exchange2010

Tags: permissions, exchange-2010, powershell, mailbox

I try set permission RO for external mailbox. I try do this with this solution

http://exchangeshare.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/how-to-setup-read-only-mailbox-in-exchange-20032007

And doesn't work. I try with PowerShell command (Add-MailboxPermission) but when I do this and then open Outlook I have full access to this external mailbox.

Anybody have some idea what I may do this?

Regards
Mick

Answer (score 0):

That's still the correct method, even in Exchange 2010.

You can't use Powershell or give Full Access through the EMC.  You have to grant Reviewer rights on the individual mailbox and the folders within that mailbox.

If you followed that article/writeup, and it still doesn't work, then you'll need to post screenshots/links to screenshots and errors that you are getting.  You'll need to include the client software used (Outlook 2010/2013, etc.).

Also, you mention "external mailbox" multiple times.  What do you mean by external?  Just another mailbox in your Exchange Org or a mailbox that's actually External to your Exchange Org?